# let $\alpha$ be a unit speed plane curve and let $\beta$ and $\gamma$ be two different involutes of $\alpha$.

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

I'm struggling with a differential geometry problem which asks:

let $\alpha$ be a unit speed plane curve and let $\beta$ and $\gamma$ be two different involutes of $\alpha$. Show that
$\beta$ and $\gamma$ are Bertrand mates.

the definition of involutes and Bertrand mates are:

Let $\alpha$ and $\beta$ be two regular curves defined on
$(a, b)$. $\beta$ is called an involute of $\alpha$ if $\beta(t_0 )$ lies on the tangent line to $\alpha$ at $t_0$ and if tangent line of $\alpha$ at
$\alpha(t_0 )$ is perpendicular to the tangent line of $\beta$ at $\beta(t_0 )$.

and

Two curves $\alpha(s)$ and $\beta(s)$ ($s$ might not be the arclength parameter for both) are called Bertrand
mates if for each $s_0$, the normal lines of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ at $s_0$ are the same lines.

as $\alpha'.\beta' =0 $ and $\alpha'.\gamma'=0$ and $\beta(s) = (c-s)\alpha'(s)+\alpha(s)$ i feel like $\alpha'$ is their normal line but I can't prove it clearly!

Comment: Since you haven’t accepted my answer on your last question, I'm not going to help on this one. I believe this problem is wrong, as well. Where are you getting these? Or is it an exam for you to prove or give a counterexample? Anyhow, you need to make more effort and give more appreciation to people who help.

Comment: Sorry again! I’ve just found out how to accept an answer:))and yes, these were some problems of a take home exam, the due date is over and our professor released their answer!he claimed that these problems had some ambiguity:/

Answer (score 1):

[image]

The normal distance between two involtes differs only by the arc length $AB$ from a point on the originating base curve. The involutes are produced by unwinding a taut sting (tangent to base curve latter part and normal to the involute pair... for that matter normal to the entire family of involutes so generated ).

The normal distance difference $AB$ is carried through towards max radius and is constant for an evolute pair satisfying  essential requirement of Bertrand curves along common normal.

In fact it *follows directly from the definition* of involutes and Bertrand curves.

For circular involutes

$$ \Delta N = 2 \pi r_{base} /n $$

and for an arbitrary convex base, equals arc length difference $\arc{AB}$ at start of unwinding i.e., between dots shown.